# Why my python only read only 1 column from a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Recently, I tried to analyze some csv files, but when I tried to read the csv file into a dataframe, I found that the dataframe had only one column, and the csv file obviously had several columns.
The csv file is a test record from a test machine，if I open it with notebook，it looks like this：

[image]

---

If I open it in excel， it looks like this(over 300 rows)：
[image]

---

**What I want to do is to take a specific part of the whole csv file(from row 323 to row 327) for analysis**, this part looks like this:

[image]

I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=';', header=None,)  #read csv with pandas
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)  #delet empty rows
df = df.iloc[215:300]   #take the data I need from dataframe
```

But when I ran df.info(), I got this error:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 85 entries, 215 to 299
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    85 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 1.3+ KB
```

There was only 1 column, and what I need was a tabular form with separated columns(like it shows in Excel) so that I could calculate those numbers.
I googled this problem and stuggled a few days，no matter what I did, I could only get 1 column.
Really need some help or guidance here，thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a CSV file. It doesn't *have* consistent columns and rows. There may be some CSV-ish data somewhere in there, but you'd need to pick out those lines specifically.

Comment: The file is taken directly from the system of a test machine， and with an ".csv"， so I mistakenly thought it was a csv file. Can you give me some advice for picking out those lines？Can I convert this file to an excel file then I can handle it as a excel with pandas？

Comment: Both CSV and Excel files need to be *tabular*. Meaning, fixed columns with a variable number of rows, each of which contains the same columns with values. Your file is far from that, it's some random text output. How to extract the data you need from that nobody here knows. Maybe you need to parse through it and look for the right headlines and then read everything after it as CSV until you hit a specific other line which ends that particular tabular data piece…

Answer (score 0):

It is a data-cleaning process, you can read the file in one column, then extract the target rows, then split and expand it.

```
# same code, just change sep='\n'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\n', header=None,)  #read csv with pandas
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)  #delet empty rows
df = df.iloc[215:300]   #take the data I need from dataframe

# split and expand(new)
dfn = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
# then save it as a new file
dfn.to_csv('new_file.csv', index=False, header=None)
# read it again
df = pd.read_csv('new_file.csv')
```

Comment: Amazing！ I can continue my work with these clean data. Turely appreciate your help！